# Google Bigquery Complex UDF

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am creating a UDF in bigquery to call in a more powerful query. The input to the UDF is a string made up of numbers and different length units. There are three main cases. See below for an explanation of the cases and also an example for each case. The "#" represents a number. "Unit" represents one of 3 distance units (Miles, Yards, and Furlongs). Case 3 is comprised of two different units that are added together. The end goal of the UDF is to normalize the input to one unit (yards), remove any alphabetic characters, and convert any complex fractions to floats. The UDF would then return back a string.

---

Cases:

1. '# Unit';        Example: Input '350 Y', Output '350'
2. '# #/#Unit';     Example: Input '5 1/2F', Output '1210'
3. '#Unit1 #Unit2'; Example:Input '4F 70Y', Output '950.002'

---

I have tried to do this using If statements. In my first attempt at this, I could only get rid of the complex fraction and two units that get added to each other. Is there a way to do many if statements to hit all possible combinations? I haven't found a way to use else-if conditional statements. Any advice, guidance, or code would be very much appreciated. I am relatively new to using SQL/bigquery so please let me know if I am doing this in a bad way. Below is my first attempt code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `location`(str STRING) AS (
(
  if(  
    REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r' ') AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'/')=FALSE #does not contain /

    , (1760 * SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, 'M',''),' ')[OFFSET(0)] AS FLOAT64)) + SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(str,' ')[OFFSET(1)] AS FLOAT64)
    ,if(
      REGEXP_CONTAINS(str, r'/'),
      SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(str,' ')[OFFSET(0)] AS FLOAT64) + SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(SPLIT(str,' ')[OFFSET(1)], '/')[OFFSET(0)] AS INT64) / SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(SPLIT(str,' ')[OFFSET(1)], '/')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64), 
      IFNULL(SAFE_CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, r'FYM','') AS FLOAT64), -1)
    )
  )

)
);
```

Comment: There are many better regex and BigQuery folks than I, but this one _seems_ to extract each component of your measurements: `[\d \/]+[FYM$ ]`. Tester here: https://regex101.com/r/tYko0x/1. And I think you can use `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` with an _occurrence_ number to grab them in the order they appear, i.e. the `4F` and `70Y` separately: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract. But I don't know much about either of your tools, so I'm just making an educated guess about where I'd start instead of doing the split/replace routine you're trying.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I’ll look into the REGEXP_EXTRACT() as a cleaner way to split up the different components. The thing that is really stumping me is how to know what unit conversion to apply to the different occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
create temp function eval (str string) returns float64
language js as r"""
  return eval(str);
""";
select str, 
  ( 
    select sum( 
      case right(x,1) 
        when 'M' then 1760
        when 'F' then 220
        when 'Y' then 1
      end * eval(replace(trim(translate(x, 'MFY', '')), ' ', '+')))
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(str, r'[^MFY]+(?:M|F|Y)')) val,
    unnest([struct(trim(val) as x)])
  ) yards
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Update (per recent comments): you can package whole stuff into js udf and sql udf as in below example

```
create temp function eval (str string) returns float64
language js as r"""
  return eval(str);
""";
create temp function to_yards(str string) as (( 
    select sum( 
      case right(x,1) 
        when 'M' then 1760
        when 'F' then 220
        when 'Y' then 1
      end * eval(replace(trim(translate(x, 'MFY', '')), ' ', '+')))
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(str, r'[^MFY]+(?:M|F|Y)')) val,
    unnest([struct(trim(val) as x)])
));
select str, to_yards(str) as yards
from your_table
```

with same output as above

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This looks very promising. I may be confused, but is there a way to call this function similar to a create or replace function, such that everything from the "Select str" down is also captured in the UDF? I currently call the create or replace function by doing `project.dataset`.function(str) inside of a query

Comment: Of course. I addressed what I thought the most challenging part with hope that you can package it to whatever you want. I recommend to leave eval part as js udf and package the sql part as a sql udf. Should be quite simple “transformation” of presented code

Comment: I really appreciate it! Sorry for the lower-level questions. I am self-taught and very new to this. The reason I asked this was I tried using both a temp function (for the js) and Create or Replace function for the SQL portion. It doesn't allow me to combine the two statements. "CREATE FUNCTION statement cannot be combined with CREATE TEMP FUNCTION statements"

Comment: you either use both as a temp function or create both as a permanent :o) i hope we are done with this one and your question is fully answered